# How change MySQL instance root user password?

Tags: mysql

I used to have a single MySQL server instance on Ubuntu but for security reasons I decided to use two instances since both test and prod applications will be open for web users. Therefore I configured two MySQL server instances and ran `mysqld_multi start` to setup the databases. My /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld0]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld0.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld0.sock
port=3306
datadir=/home/prod/data
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error0.log

[mysqld1]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock
port=3307
datadir=/home/test/data
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error1.log
```

Using `mysqld_multi start 0,1` I start both instances but can not access them with root user - geting access denied for root on localhost.

I have tried to follow these instructions (providing additional --socket parameter) https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/ as they did help me before but for no use.

When connected to MySQL in safe mode I also see previous users that were set up in the original instance.

Maybe I understand multi MySQL server instances and how they should work in the wrong way? Does all instances share same users? How do I get access to the newly created instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to run mysqld_safe with additional parameters - providing dirs for each instance `mysqld_safe --mysqld=/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/home/test/data/mysql --datadir=/home/test/data --skip-grant-tables`. After that everything went as expected

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in SQL

For MySQL 5.7.6 or later you can do

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';
```

Or for MySQL 5.7.5 or earlier you can do

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPassword');
```

Comment: How is this different from `update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';`? After running this update successfuly I get nowhere:/

Comment: I tried to run these queries and as suspected I got message that they can not be executed because of --skip-grant-tables.